# How can I have a <core-selector> inline?

Tags: html, polymer, core-elements

I would like to use a 'core-selector', but I don't want the 'core-selection'-elements on top of each other. I tried replacing the div's with span's, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Edit: I was asked to post code. I have done exactly like in the example from the  [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector), and the result is like the demo (link on the same page). But I would like the options on one row.

Comment: What do you mean by inline? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried replacing the div's with span's, but that didn't work.

Check your work. `core-selector` doesn't care about the item layout.

```
<core-selector selected="0">
  <span>Item 1 </span>
  <span>Item 2 </span>
  <span>Item 3 </span>
</core-selector>
```

http://jsbin.com/robola/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS so the divs inside core-selector are inline, and then they will display horizontally instead of vertically.

```
core-selector.list div {
   display: inline;
}
```